# How to link an array to a javascript function in html?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Hi I'm new to Javascript and I'm really confused at how to actually call functions. I'm not sure why this isn't working and would love some input.

#### My HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="problem2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Answer" VALUE="Click to see Answer" onClick="MyFunction(array);">
    <div id="answer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### My JavaScript :

```
var array = [3, 1, 1, 'a', 'a', 3, 'b', 'f', 'a', 1, 'a'];

function MyFunction(array) {
    var counter = 0,
        amount = 1,
        highest;

    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        for(var j=i; j<array.length;j++) {
            if (array(i) ===array(j)){
                counter++;
            }
            if(counter>amount){
                amount=counter;
                highest=array[i];
            }
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML(highest + " " + amount + times");
}
```

Comment: lot of typos - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d7huq7kf/2/

Answer (score 4):

You have several errors in your function, first to access to an array item you should use bracket `[]` and not `()`, e.g :

```
if (array[i] === array[j]){
     counter++;
}
```

You miss a double quote `"` in the following line, also to assign HTML using `innerHTML` you should follow it by `=` :

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML(highest + " " + amount + times");
```

Should be :

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = highest + " " + amount + "times";
```

And you don't have to pass the array from HTML since the array already defined in JS code so just use it :

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Answer" VALUE="Click to see Answer" onClick="MyFunction();">

//Define function without argument
function MyFunction() {
   //your code here
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Working Snippet

```js
var array = [3, 1, 1, 'a', 'a', 3, 'b', 'f', 'a', 1, 'a'];

function MyFunction() {
  var counter = 0;
  var amount = 1;
  var highest;
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++)
  {
    for(var j=i; j<array.length;j++){
      if (array[i] === array[j]){
        counter++;
      }

      if(counter>amount){
        amount=counter;
        highest=array[i];
      }
    }
    counter = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = highest + " " + amount + "times";
}
```

```html
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Answer" VALUE="Click to see Answer" onClick="MyFunction();">
  <div id="answer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working copy of the code you provided & a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5ftrb3fp/) for it

```
<body>
  <script>
    var array = [3, 1, 1, 'a', 'a', 3, 'b', 'f', 'a', 1, 'a'];

    function MyFunction(array) {
      var counter = 0;
      var amount = 1;
      var highest;
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
          if (array[i] === array[j]) {
            counter++;
          }

          if (counter > amount) {
            amount = counter;
            highest = array[i];
          }
        }
        counter = 0;
      }

      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = highest + " " + amount + " times";
      }

  </script>
  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Answer" VALUE="Click to see Answer" onClick="MyFunction(array)">
  <div id="answer"></div>
```